# Can't connect to the fakeredis instance (Nodejs + Redis + Fakeredis)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, redis

I write nodejs app with redis. I want to mock my redis connection in the unit tests. I use fakeredis module to stub my data.
But i have problem with getting redis keys created in the tests. I can get all keys in tests, but they are unavaiable in code.

It's like my code doesn't connect to the fakeredis instance.
I tried to set port and host, also tried another module redis-mock.

App:

```js
var redis = require('redis');
var redisClient = redis.createClient(6379, '127.0.0.1', {});

redisClient.keys('*', function(error, reply){
    console.log('KEYS', reply); // Problem: it's empty array 
});
```

Spec:

```js
var assert    = require('chai').assert;
var fakeredis = require('fakeredis');
var fakeredisClient;

before(function() {
    fakeredisClient = fakeredis.createClient();
});

beforeEach(function() {

    // Mock data - Set random keys
    fakeredisClient.set('FOO', 'BAR');

});

afterEach(function(done){
    fakeredisClient.flushdb(function(err, reply){
        assert.ok(reply);
        done();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that are incorrect in your code above.

First you need to mock your `fakeredis` module in place of the `redis` module in your application code. One way to do this is using the `mockery` library.

The next issue is that your `fakeredis.createClient(...)` call in your test must match the `redis.createClient(...)` call in your application code. This means that you will need to read in the same configuration variables into your test. Another option is to use `sinon` to overload the `fakeredis.createClient()` function to always return our test `client`.

```
var mockery = require('mockery')
  , fakeredis = require('fakeredis')

  /* This should exactly match the app connection settings 
     if you aren't stubbing the createClient() method using 
     sinon. */
  , client = fakeredis.createClient('test') 

  /* If your connection settings aren't an exact match (or 
     use the defaults via an empty constructor, you need to 
     stub using sinon */
  , sinon = require('sinon')

// run before the tests start
before(function() {

    // Enable mockery to mock objects
    mockery.enable({
        warnOnUnregistered: false
    });

    // Stub the createClient method to *always* return the client created above
    sinon.stub(fakeredis, 'createClient', function(){ return client; } );

    // Override the redis module with our fakeredis instance
    mockery.registerMock('redis', fakeredis);
}

// run after each test
afterEach(function(){
    client.flushdb();
});
```